# Nautilus Connect To Server Can't type in GUI

Tags: nautilus

When I have Nautilus open and I select File->Connect To Server... The window that opens up wont let me type in any of the fields. I have no idea why it would do this. It has worked previously, but somewhere along the line it started doing this. I'm not quite sure what changed that made this happen. It occurs with any of the "types" that are selected from the combo box as well.

Any ideas on what I can do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Can you type in the address bar? Press Ctrl-L to enable it.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. It seems the GUI has changed a bit since 12.04 (Gnome) I just followed the suggestion format and entered ssh:/// and then my target IP I wonder if this is why I am having problems with Samba.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. What version are you running?

Comment: My version says 3.4.2

Comment: I can use the address bar, but it still won't get me to the network location I need. I can use Dolphin to access the network locations I want to get to so I know I have access. For now, I've switched my default file manager to Dolphin.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem with Nautilus on Budgie 20.10. What I did was to:

```
sudo apt install gvfs-backends
```

I restarted Nautilus and was able to connect to the remote server.